# I changed the name of the SPAdmin Content DB and now I get a 404 error when I go to Central Admin

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, central-administration

I changed the name of our Sharepoint_AdminContent db (to remove the GUID) using the script below and now I get a 404 error when trying to browse to Central Administration. SharePoint 2013. Verified in IIS that the app pool is running.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

## List all web applications

```
Get-SPWebApplication -IncludeCentralAdministration

$CentralAdminUrl = "http://sp2013v2:2013/"
$CentralAdminDB = Get-SPContentDatabase -WebApplication $CentralAdminUrl
```

## Verify the database object is good

```
$CentralAdminDB.Name
```

## New DB Name

```
$NewCentralAdminDBName = "01_Content_NewCentralAdmin"
$NewCentralAdminContentDB = New-SPContentDatabase -Name $NewCentralAdminDBName -WebApplication $CentralAdminUrl -MaxSiteCount 2 -WarningSiteCount 1
```

## Verify the database is added

```
Get-SPContentDatabase -WebApplication $CentralAdminUrl
```

## Verify the database object is good

```
$NewCentralAdminContentDB
```

## Move the Sites to nicely named DB

```
$CentralAdminDB.Sites | % {Move-SPSite $_ -DestinationDatabase $NewCentralAdminContentDB -Confirm:$false -Verbose}
iisreset
```

## Verify the Site collection are moved

```
Get-SPContentDatabase -WebApplication $CentralAdminUrl
```

## If databases are moved then dismount the orignal DB

```
Dismount-SPContentDatabase $CentralAdminDB -Confirm:$false -Verbose
```

## Confirm First Database is gone

```
Get-SPContentDatabase -WebApplication $CentralAdminUrl
```

## Delete the database from SQL Server

Comment: Did you do an iisreset?

Comment: Yes. Didn't work. :(

Comment: I confirmed that the app pool is running. The app pool is running under the farm admin account, but the db itself is "owned" by different admin account. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Maybe. Who was the owner of old db?

Comment: Ashamed to say I don't know. I know the 2 possible owners, though.

Comment: How is the owner of new db a different user? It is a service account? You should do all this using farm account. Atleast for admin content db.

Comment: how many sites listed after this command: $d = Get-SPContentDatabase -WebApplication $CentralAdminUrl      $d.sites

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP that returns: "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$null

Comment: We only have one site.

Comment: If I run the SharePoint Configuration Wizard now, will that resolve this perhaps?

Comment: You can try `$NewCentralAdminContentDB.RefreshSitesInConfigurationDatabase`